# How to apply focus() for a particular HTML table column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to apply the focus() function if the user enters invalid data in the HTML table column.

Please find my JavaScript function below:

```
function validate(tableID)
{
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var rows=table.rows;
        var data = [];
        var cells;
        for (var n = 1; n < rowCount; n++) {
            cells = rows[n].cells;
            data.push([
                cells[0].firstElementChild.checked,
                cells[1].firstElementChild.value,
                cells[2].firstElementChild.value,
                cells[3].firstElementChild.value,
                cells[4].firstElementChild.value
           ]);
            if (regex1.test(cells[3].firstElementChild.value) == false) {
                alert('Please enter valid pan number');
                document.getElementById('txtRow3').rows[n].cells[3].focus();
                return false;
            }
        }
```

In the above function I tried the below line to focus the fourth cell of the table row, if the user entered invalid data. But it is not working.
document.getElementById('txtRow3').rows[n].cells[3].focus();

Kindly help..Thank You!

Comment: Are you trying to highlight the field which failed the regex test? If so `cells[3].firstElementChild.focus()` will work

Comment: What is `cells[3]`? textbox, div, span?

Comment: You can not focus a table cell without the `tabindex` attribute. Do you mean that you want to focus a child input?